# Interesting SQL join using between dates and a time stamp

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime, join, timestamp

Thanks to anyone who helps me solve this problem, I am using SQL 17.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
select * from ContractDim

| UserID | ContractID | BusinessLine |   StartDate   |   EndDate   |
    1          111           AAA        01/06/2016      31/08/2016
    1          222           AAA        01/01/2015      31/05/2015
```

And another one like this

```
select * from NonWorkingDays

| UserID |  NonWorkingDay  |   
    1         02/07/2016     
    1         14/06/2016
    1         03/05/2015
    1         14/02/2015
```

So what I want to do is to add the contract number for each `NonWorkingday`. Results should be:

```
| UserID |  NonWorkingDay  |  ContractID  |
    1         02/07/2016         111
    1         14/06/2016         111
    1         03/05/2015         222
    1         14/02/2015         222
```

How do I go about doing this? 
I'm stuck here and neither Google nor Baidu (I'm in China) have helped.

Comment: Have you tried to run any query to get your desired result? I suggest you read about `join` and give it a try, post your failed attempt (if you failed), then you'd get better and more help.

Comment: Edit your question and show us your current query attempt.  Also, tell us which database you are actually using (I'm guessing you're not really using both MySQL and SQL Server at the same time).  Finally, what is the _type_ of your date columns?  Are you storing those dates as plain text?

Comment: Please tag your right database Server

Comment: @JCee what is `SQL 17` ? Do you mean MS SQL Server 2017?

Comment: @JCee Santos, cross join is your friend. Cross join ContractDim and NonWorkingDays.

Comment: Thanks @DeanSavović, and thanks all for guiding me into a more specific way to formulate my questions since I am considerably new to SQL and stackoverflow. We worked out a way together with one of my colleagues during lunch time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we went for lunch and with a fresher mind we came up with this, which is quite obvious but we couldn't see it for a while.
All date variables are of *type* date and we use SQL Server

```
SELECT tc.UserID, t.NonWorkingDay, tc.ContractID, tc.StartDate, tc.EndDate
FROM NonWorkingDays AS t
INNER JOIN ContractDim AS tc ON tc.UserID = t.UserID 
WHERE t.NonWorkingDays BETWEEN tc.StartDate AND tc.EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN. I hope it will work for you.

```
SELECT 
W.UserID
,W.NonWorkingDay
,C.ContractID
FROM NonWorkingDays W
INNER JOIN ContractDim C 
ON C.UserID = W.UserID 
AND W.NonWorkingDay >= C.StartDate 
AND W.NonWorkingDay <= C.EndDate
```

Comment: If it is helpful. you don't forget award.